# Flask – How to use data of one function into another function for same template

Tags: python-2.7, flask

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("Main.html")

@app.route("/input",methods=["POST","GET"])
def input():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        D = pandas.read_csv(f.filename,encoding ="ISO-8859-1")
        H = del_col(D)
        B = clean(H)
        D = data_csv(B)
        frq = count(B)
        frq1 = pandas.DataFrame(frq)
        frq1["Category"]= frq1.index
        frq1.index = range(0,len(frq1))
        frq1["Count"] = frq1[0]
        del frq1[0]
        sum = frq1["Count"].sum()
    return render_template("Page22.html",frq1=frq1,sum =sum , D =D)

@app.route("/input",methods=["GET"])
def download_csv():
     # I want to get D dataframe here 
    return render_template("Page22.html",frq1=frq1,sum =sum)
```

I am new to flask. I want to use data of variable used in first function in the second function. How do I pass data of D variable from input function to the download_csv function?

Comment: You want to pass `D = data_csv(B)` from `input` to `download_csv`?

Comment: Yes, i want dataframe D from input function into download_csv function.